# How to call an extended procedure from a function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, user-defined-functions, extended-procedures

hi im having trouble trying to get the following function to work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test ( @nt_group VARCHAR(128) )
RETURNS @nt_usr TABLE (
      [name] [nchar](128) NULL
    , [type] [char](8) NULL
    , [privilege] [char](9) NULL
    , [mapped login name] [nchar](128) NULL
    , [permission path] [nchar](128) NULL
    )
AS BEGIN 

    INSERT  INTO @nt_usr
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\USER', @nt_group
     RETURN
   END
```

As far as i know i should be allowed to call an extended stored procedure, im getting the following error

> Mes 443, Level 16, State 14

Could it be that xp_logininfo might return different result sets depending on the parameters? When i use openquery i can overcome this by setting this: SET FMTONLY OFF. Does anyone know if there's a similar workaround for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because this xp returns data. Even though you are loading a table.

Basically, xps in udfs are a non-starter... I'd use a stored procedure

From [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755(SQL.90).aspx)

> **Calling Extended Stored Procedures from Functions**
>
> The extended stored procedure, when it
>   is called from inside a function,
>   cannot return result sets to the
>   client. Any ODS APIs that return
>   result sets to the client will return
>   FAIL. The extended stored procedure
>   could connect back to an instance of
>   SQL Server; however, it should not try
>   to join the same transaction as the
>   function that invoked the extended
>   stored procedure.
>
> Similar to invocations from a batch or
>   stored procedure, the extended stored
>   procedure will be executed in the
>   context of the Windows security
>   account under which SQL Server is
>   running. The owner of the stored
>   procedure should consider this when
>   giving EXECUTE permission on it to
>   users.

Comment: oh i didnt see that when i read it. I wanted to use a function so i could use cross apply in a view. i guess i should try to find someother way of doing it. thanks!